# How to only run certain lines of code in production on google cloud run?

Tags: python, docker, containers, google-cloud-run, fastapi

I'm writing FastAPI services and deploying to Google Cloud Run.

I would like to run certain code on my laptop, certain code on cloud run, etc.
I would like to customize the code based on the environment it is run in.

How can I know if I am in a container, google cloud run, my Mac laptop, vscode spaces, GitHub actions...How can I add that information to debug variable?

```
    debug,cloud,laptop,vcode = Environment()
    if debug:
        app.mount("/public", StaticFiles(directory="/public"), name="static")
    else:
        app.mount("/public", StaticFiles(directory="/debitcard/debitcard/public/static"), name="static")
    }
```

How can I know in python if the code is actually running on my laptop or the cloud run environment?

Comment: You can set environmental variables, based on which you can decide which code to run

Comment: pretty much set env var in all the environments the code runs huh. got it.

Comment: That's how you do in nodejs, or use a configuration properties file like in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to simply set environment variables in all the environments the code will run.

On my laptop, I'll do this:

```
 export DEBUG=True
 export LAPTOP=True
 export CLOUDRUN=False
 export GITHUBACTIONS=False
```

and on Google Cloud Run, I'll set the environment vars aswell.
aswell as on GitHub Actions....